# NoSQL and lack of support in R

Tags: r, database, dplyr, sparklyr

I'm working with a quite large dataset which comes in csv files (8 per year for 20 years), with an average of 9 million entries per year with about 19 variables.
As I'm doing some time-series studies, including network analysis and PCA, FA, etc... I thought that working with csv files doesn't make much sense, as the queries might range from one quarter(2 files) to 4 or 5 years.

However, I've been reading that NoSQL is faster and more efficient when dealing with big data, which is a pity as packages such as dplyr or sparklyr work mainly with SQL databases.
I also didn't find many alternatives for working with NoSQL databases in R.

Am I missing something here, or is simply NoSQL a terrible idea to use in R for what I want to do?

Comment: 9 million rows can definitely still be handled pretty quickly by fread. Anything that fits in memory is probably fine to use a csv for, but I'd check out the data.table package to make it faster.

Comment: @be_green, unfortunately I run into memory problems when I try to do left_joins, etc... I have 8Gb ram, but it seems that it's not enough. But again, 9 million is only for one year, and I often have to run queries on 4 or 5 years.

Comment: Oh ok, fair enough! If you are running into memory limits then you should definitely be looking at something other than data.table :) But at the same time, it might be a short term fix to your problems because it doesn't copy anything, and instead does operations by reference. dplyr on the other hand does make copies of your data in memory.